# Open app menu item from webview

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, zxing, launch

I am trying to launch an intent to open the zxing barcode scanner from a link in a webview.

I have created a menu item that launches the zxing scanner from the menu, when someone hits the menu button on their phone.  But some tablets don't have that menu button, so I need to add access to the scanner from the webview.

I have no clue where to start.  I figured there would be a way to add a javascript code to the webview, that when someone clicks on a link, it calls the android:id="@+id/scanNow" or something equivalent.

Or is there a way for me to launch:

```
case R.id.scanNow:      
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN.SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    return true;
```

from the html web page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is to have some javascript in your webview and link it to your Android application. For that, you will need to use [addJavascriptInterface](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String%29).

Check out [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html#BindingJavaScript) and [this link](http://blog.objectgraph.com/index.php/2012/03/16/android-development-javascript-bridge-example-fully-explained/) for more explanations.